# Twitch Api - Changing channel status fail via jQuery Ajax put method

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, put, twitch

Good day. 
Im trying to change stream title via this code:

```
titleStr = "Playing cool new game!";

$.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/my_channel?channel[status]='+titleStr+'&oauth_token=' +token,
            type: 'PUT',
            dataType : 'jsonp',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(data) {
              console.log(data.status);
            }
});
```

It returns succsess (current title), but nothing changes.
However i tested url with Chrome App named **Postman** and its perfectly works.

UPD: [Twitch API](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/v2_resources/channels.md#parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved. Twitch api have an undoc feature '&_method=put' thru 'GET' =\

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/mychannel?channel[status]='+titleStr+'&oauth_token=' +token+'&_method=put',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data) {
              console.log(data.status);
            }
});
```

This code works well.